# very confused on the working of *target++ = *source++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

So, I have done my reading, and I understand what *p++ means, and the basics of how *target++ = *source++ works. But I am mighty baffled by the results I am getting.

I want to copy the contents of an array into another. Simple enough, except if you look at how the contents of the array change as the program run, I don't have the first clue why this is the output...

**Here is my program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(int *array, int size){

    printf("{ ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%d, ", array[i]);
    printf("}");

    printf("\n");
}

void copyArray(int *target, int *source, int size){

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        printf("Iteration #%d \n",i+1 );
        printf("Source Array: ");
        printArray(source, 5);

        printf("Target Array: ");
        printArray(target, 5);
        printf("\n");   

        *target++ = *source++; 
    }

}

int main(void){

    int source[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int target[5] = {0};

    copyArray(target, source, 11);


    return 0;
}
```

**And this is my output as it runs:**

Iteration #1
Source Array: { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, }
Target Array: { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, }

Iteration #2
Source Array: { 2, 3, 4, 5, 32767, }
Target Array: { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, }

Iteration #3
Source Array: { 3, 4, 5, 32767, -732409276, }
Target Array: { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, }

Iteration #4
Source Array: { 4, 5, 32767, -732409276, 1442845569, }
Target Array: { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, }

Iteration #5
Source Array: { 5, 32767, -732409276, 1442845569, 1583093720, }
Target Array: { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, }

Iteration #6
Source Array: { 32767, -732409276, 1442845569, 1583093720, 32767, }
Target Array: { 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, }

Iteration #7
Source Array: { -732409276, 1442845569, 1583093720, 32767, -1844984375, }
Target Array: { 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, }

Iteration #8
Source Array: { 1442845569, 1583093720, 32767, -1844984375, 32767, }

Target Array: { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, }

Iteration #9
Source Array: { 1583093720, 32767, -1844984375, 32767, -1844984375, }
Target Array: { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, }

**So a couple of immediate questions I have are:**
1) when I call the function I pass it "target" which is a pointer to the first element of the array. Why does my target array start filling from its last position?

2)I don't have any code in there, at least not any voluntary code, that modifies the values of my "source" array. Why are those changing?

3)My first version of this program used a pointer to the last element of source to stop the loop inside copyArray, but then while running gdb I noticed it was taking more iterations to return the function than there are elements in the array, and I got curious. By trial and error I discovered it takes 9 iterations of the loop inside copyArray() to fully copy "source" into "target". Why is that?

Any thoughts on the matter?

*edited for readability

Comment: `*target++ = *source++` will modify the `target` and `source` pointers.

Comment: Undefined behavior.  `copyArray(target, source, 11);` should be `copyArray(target, source, 5);`

Comment: You have arrays of size 5 but copy 11 elements.  This is undefined behavior, so your program could do anything at all.

Comment: I understand *target++ = *source++ changes my pointers...it is meant to...what it isn't meant to do is change the values inside my source array. And 11 is the lowest number of iterations that is needed to fill the target array with the correct values. Smack that code in a .c and see it go :)

Comment: You keep changing the values, but then keep passing the new values into printArray, which is starting at the *new* position of the pointer and going 5 values past that.

Comment: that's it. Smacked me right in the face with that one :)

Comment: Another day, another one of these barmy questions. Stop writing awful code like `*a++ = *b++`. Just _stop it and top it_!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to modify the `target` and `source` pointers but you need to call `printArray` using the original pointers, not the moving ones.  Otherwise, after the first iteration, instead of printing indices 0..4 you're printing 1..5, then 2..6, then 3..7... Those all have undefined values, and in this particular case you eventually end up running into `target` when trying to print `source` (after iteration 5).

You need to do something like this:

```
int* source_original = source;
int* target_original = target;
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    printf("Iteration #%d \n",i+1 );
    printf("Source Array: ");
    printArray(source_original, 5);

    printf("Target Array: ");
    printArray(target_original, 5);
    printf("\n");   

    *target++ = *source++; 
}
```

Comment: Absolutely correct...I ended up making the calls with pritArray(source-i, 5)

Answer (score 0):

```
void copyArray(int *target, int *source, int size){
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
      printf("Iteration #%d \n",i+1 );
      printf("Source Array: ");
      printArray(source, 5);

      printf("Target Array: ");
      printArray(target, 5);
      printf("\n");   

      *target++ = *source++; 
  }
```

}

You can't do this.  You keep changing where target and source point, and then printing starting from this new value.  It's like reading the numbers off houses on a street that only has 5 houses and then a cliff.  By the time you get to 5, you're reading off the last house and then walking off the cliff to read 4 more numbers.

The only reason your target array seems to be correct is probably because of the values getting copied on the stack.  Try this instead.

```
void copyArray(int *target, int *source, int size){
  int * originalTarget = target, int * originalSource = source;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
      printf("Iteration #%d \n",i+1 );
      printf("Source Array: ");
      printArray(originalSource, 5);

      printf("Target Array: ");
      printArray(originalTarget, 5);
      printf("\n");   

      *target++ = *source++; 
  }
```

}

Now event though you're changing `target` and `source`, the values you print out will always be starting from the original pointers, and thus safe to iterate across.  This should allow you to change your main function to call copyArrays like so

```
copyArray(target, source, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't don't c++ since the dinosaurs where running about.

However I think the line:
`*target++ = *source++`; 
Is not doing what you think.
I think what is happening is that the *source++ reads some unknown (next sequentcial memorie adddress) as an integer value.

```
copyArray(int &target, int &source, int size)
```